# Terminal not executing command

Tags: terminal, zsh, ventura

For some reason my pointer in terminal isn't blinking which means when I type a command e.g. twillio it does not do anything. I have attached screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: The question?  Have you tried `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: There's something wrong in one of your shell initialization files; from the window header, something to do with an "ng completion script". You'll have to examine the files to find the problem.

Comment: Did you look in your zsh startup files for the place where `compdef` is used/called?

Comment: @nohillside I use terminal just to start for node that is all I know, so don't know what `compdef` mean

Comment: It doesn't matter what it means, the key point is that it gets called from `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` in the wrong way. So please have a look at these files, look for this string and copy/paste (*as text*, not as picture) the relevant part (let's see 5 lines before and 5 lines after) *into* the question (there is an edit link for this).

Comment: I don't quite understand why the blinking or non-blinking of the cursor is important. After all, you define in Terminal.app how the cursor should look like. I would instead fix first the errors in your zsh startup files. Reconfigure your Terminal preferences so that the shell is started with the `-x` option, and then analyze the output to debug the error.

Comment: @user1934428 the non-blinking indicated that Terminal isn’t accepting any input right now.

Comment: Not sure whether this is correct. At least [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/change-the-terminal-window-cursor-trml15226/mac) Apple support page says that you configure the blinking/non-blinking. The fact that your zsh is not ready yet, is rather indicated by a lack of a prompt. In any case, without debugging your startup files you won't find the root cause of the problems.

Comment: @user1934428 of course it‘s configurable, but most people don‘t. And the screenshot clearly shows that the shell is stuck during startup and does not accept any input yet.